# Adding new attribute to a konvajs group object

Tags: javascript, canvas, attributes, konvajs

How can I add a new attribute to an existing `Konva.Group()` object?

for example:

```js
var myRoom = {
  title: "living room",
  group: new Konva.Group({
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    draggable: true
  })
};

myRoom.group.setAttr("obj", myRoom);
myRoom.group.on('dblclick', function(evt) {
  console.log('room obj', evt.target.getAttr("obj"));
});
```

The attribute "obj" is `undefined! So how can I add it to the Group obj and be able to retrieve it properly?

Comment: Have you tried `myRoom.group.obj = myRoom;`?

Comment: yep, still "evt.target.getAttr("obj")" & "evt.target.obj" are undefined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`evt.target` is reference to a shape that you dbclicked.

To get reference to `Group` instance you may use `this`:

```
myRoom.group.on('dblclick', function(evt) {
  console.log(evt.target);  // circle
  console.log(this);   // group
  console.log('room obj', this.getAttr("obj"));
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/qsyw4bqm/

Note: in new version of `Konva` (0.11.0) you will be able to use `evt.currentTarget` as such reference.